# sql matching strings with given all letters anywhere

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to match the words with given all characters and characters  can be anywhere in the word but all of given characters  should be include in the matching string

Ex :

```
1   BMW
4   LAND ROVER
6   VOLVO
9   IVECO
14  VOLKSWAGEN
20  CHEVROLET
```

given word is "VW"  then result should be

```
14  VOLKSWAGEN
```

Comment: mysql or SQL-Server?

Comment: MS sql  why people are given - point for my question ?

Comment: Because you do not Show what you have tried

Comment: With just 'VW', you can't do much in this table. If you really want to use that, I suggest you add a column with abbreviations or something like that.

Comment: You need another table, with all official names and their nick-names. VW Volkswagen, Chevrolet - Chevy etc.

Comment: What you want is possible (see my answer), but this is the wrong approach: You should maintain a side table `BrandAlias`, where you fill in all known aliases / abbreviations and the brand name itself. This is linked with a decent ID. Do your searches there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,YourWord VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
 (1,'BMW')
,(4,'LAND ROVER')
,(6,'VOLVO')
,(9,'IVECO')
,(14,'VOLKSWAGEN')
,(20,'CHEVROLET');
```

--Your search word (should not contain a letter twice...)

```
DECLARE @GivenWord VARCHAR(100)='VW';
```

--The first CTE picks as many running numbers, as there are letters in the given word (the count of sys.objects should suffice...)

```
WITH Numbers AS
(
    SELECT TOP (LEN(@GivenWord)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Nr
    FROM sys.objects
)
```

--The second CTE picks each letter separately

```
,EachChar AS
(
SELECT SUBSTRING(@GivenWord,Nr,1) AS C
FROM  Numbers
)
```

--The main query `CROSS JOIN`s and filters those, where the letter is part of the word

```
SELECT YourWord
FROM @tbl AS tbl
CROSS JOIN EachChar
WHERE tbl.YourWord LIKE '%' + EachChar.C + '%'
GROUP BY tbl.YourWord
HAVING COUNT(YourWord)=LEN(@GivenWord)
```

The `HAVING` checks if the found count equals to the length of the given word. That means: All characters exist in the search word

Comment: @LittleDragon, well, on SO people dislike a simple *Please do my job*-question. It is somehow polite to show the own effort and explain the problem actually occured. Not just a simple *I need a query for XY*-question...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM [Table_name] WHERE brand LIKE '%V%' AND brand LIKE '%W%';
```

Comment: The word "VW" is dynamic.

Comment: Dynamically set letter in the words and above

Comment: The challenge is to split the given word in its single characters. Your approach would need dynamically created `WHERE` clause with as many `LIKE`s as there are letters in the given word. Doing this hard coded is not an answer to the actual question...